# Which is more efficient? (Garbage Collection)

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

Okay my question is the following: 
Say you have a class like below. During run time:
Will a new action listener be created every time the loop is being run? 
Is the second class much more efficient that the first? 
In the first class are there 100 new ActionListener Objects being created?

```
public class Foo extends JFrame {
    public Foo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JTextField someField = new JTextField();
            someField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

VERSUS A CLASS LIKE:

```
public class Foo extends JFrame {
    public Foo() {
        ActionListener someActionListener = new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //DO SOMETHING HERE
            }
        }; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JTextField someField = new JTextField();
            someField.addActionListener(someActionListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would that first one not create 100 anonymous inner classes?

Comment: @lynks: Anonymous inner classes are created while compiling the code, so there will be only one anonymous inner class in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will a new action listener be created every time the loop is being
>   run?

In the first class, yes.

> Is the second class much more efficient that the first?

The second class gives each new `JTextField()` object the same action listener. This is more efficient (saves some memory). However, you should know that all 100 `JTextField()` objects have **the same action listener**.

Also, if you are going to have this be the case, you should move `someActionListener = new ActionListener()` into the constructor of `Foo`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just another quick question. In the second class, Could several threads call methods of the someActionListener simultaneously?

Comment: @foklepoint In theory yes, but they wouldn't because there is only one GUI Event Thread.

Answer (score 4):

the second example could save 1-2 KB (which is worth about 0.003 cents) but given the functionality is not the same, correctness is more important.

by comparison 1 second of your time on minimum wage is worth 0.2 cents so if you spent even a fraction of a second thinking about it, it could have been a waste of time. ;)

Comment: :)) But, if he spent that time learning not to think about it next time, the balance is still positive :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik A thought for you: Which cost more money, the memory used by `float` and `double` or the fact `double` has one more letter? The cost of typing one letter is over 100x more.  The cost of a bug caused by having less precision in float can be 1000x more again. ;)

Comment: Well, to be fair, a single typed `double` can imply a billion `double`s in runtime :) But still, there's next to zero reason to ever consider a `float`, especially on a 64-bit JVM. Except if you happen to be implementing Lucene, they even have byte-sized floats there!

Answer (score 2):

In the first program, you are running `new ActionListener()` 100 times. You will end up with 100 `ActionListener` objects.

In the second program, you only run `new ActionListener()` once. So you will only end up with 1 `ActionListener` object.

Clearly, in the first program, you are taking up a bunch more memory. But the programs are not equivalent, as in the first, each `JTextField` has its own `ActionListener`, where in the second, they all share one.